# How to make a Restful Password Reminder and change User email field to username field with Laravel 5.0?

Tags: php, mysql, email, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make the password reminder with Laravel 5.0, my `user` table is setted in config/auth.php as the correct table to make this but the table don't has a field email because in my business username is more appropiated than email to be the users email property.

So, when I try to call POST /password/username (in my case I need to create a postUsername method in my PasswordController that make use from ResetsPasswords `trait` because I have a username not a email and I can't rename username field to email), I get the following mysql error:

`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from`user`where`email`= email@email.com limit 1`

How to change the default behavior of Password Reminder in Laravel 5.0 to make use from username field instead email field?

I try to make use from mutator(setter) and accessor(getter) method to email but not working, this way:

```
<?php
// class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract...

public function getEmail() {
    return $this->username;
}

public function setEmail($email) {
    return $this->username = $email;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting a getEmailForPasswordReset method on User model solves the problem:

```
<?php
public function getEmailForPasswordReset() {
    return $this->username;
}
```

And my PasswordController to works with POST /password/username/{token} field instead email field:

```
<?php namespace Reverse\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Reverse\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Create a new password controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker  $passwords
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth, PasswordBroker $passwords)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->passwords = $passwords;

        // With this, when logged says: "You're logged!" and not send the email token
        //$this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postUsername(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = \Validator::make(
            ['username' => $request->get('username')],
            ['username' => 'required|email|min:6|max:255']
        );

        if($validator->passes()) {
            $response = $this->passwords->sendResetLink($request->only('username'), function ($m) {
                $m->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
            });

            switch ($response) {
                case PasswordBroker::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                    return \Response::json(['success' => 'true']);
                    //return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));

                case PasswordBroker::INVALID_USER:
                    return \Response::json(['success' => 'true', 'status' => trans($response)]);
                    //return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['username' => trans($response)]);
            }
        } else {
            return \Response::json(['error' => [
                'messages' => $validator->getMessageBag(),
                'rules' => $validator->getRules()
            ]]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postReset(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required|email|min:6|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only(
            'username', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );

        $response = $this->passwords->reset($credentials, function($user, $password)
        {
            $user->password = bcrypt($password);
            $user->save();
            $this->auth->login($user);
        });

        switch ($response)
        {
            case PasswordBroker::PASSWORD_RESET:
                return \Response::json(['success' => 'true']);
                //return redirect($this->redirectPath());

            default:
                return \Response::json(['success' => 'false', 'status' => trans($response)]);
                /*return redirect()->back()
                    ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                    ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);*/
        }
    }

}
```

I change the reset view too...

```
// /resources/views/auth/reset.blade.php
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
```

I change my /config/mail.php configuration file to make use from env variables like a new SMTP_HOST variable on .env configuration file:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('SMTP_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('SMTP_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_DEFAULT', 'admin@127.0.0.1'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_NAME_DEFAULT', 'Admin')
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('SMTP_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('SMTP_USERNAME', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' => env('SMTP_PASSWORD', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail "Pretend"
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
    | web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
    | you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
    |
    */

    'pretend' => false,

];
```

And now, works fine!