# change used column in reset Password

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I'm working in a Laravel 5.2 application. I was implementing the authentication module. The thing is that I don't have a column named *email* instead of that I have a *mail* column, that's because I'm not using the default User table of the module.
So, by now the registering, loging and logout are working correctly because in the AuthController I set:

```
protected $username = 'mail';
```

But, in other hand, the *ResetPassword* is not working, because is still looking for the `email` column and it's giving me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = sredny.nevermind92@gmail.com limit 1
```

I don't want that it compares `email`, instead  I need `mail`

Comment: Try to override the  function `loginUsername()` on `https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L141` by `return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'mail';`

Answer (score 0):

Settingup the `getEmailForPasswordReset()` method on User model like:

```
public function getEmailForPasswordReset() {
    //Place you reset code here...
}
```

REF: [change User email field to username field with Laravel 5.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268071/how-to-make-a-restful-password-reminder-and-change-user-email-field-to-username)

You also need to Override `postLogin()' otherwise default authentication system will not match the credentials.